# Unknown symbol error with closed source proprietary modules

Tags: android, module, linux-kernel

I am having a problem with some proprietary modules. I am working with Mediatek android kernel and they have lots of proprietary modules and some of them show up Unkown symbol error when insmoded. AFAIK Unknown symbol is due to missing EXPORT_SYMBOL of those variables in the kernel source.

Since those are proprietary module, there is no declaration and definition of those missing symbols in the kernel source and hence kernel doesn't have those symbols and those proprietary modules fail to load.

Can anyone please tell me how do I deal with this?
Really GPL doesn't cover these modules enforcing manufacturer to release their sources?

Answer (score 0):

Insmod'ng the modules whose dependencies you may not know will result in the errors like you mentioned. Try `modprobe` instead. It will take care of the dependency.
If it gives a similar problem again, run `depmod` and follow it up with modprobe.

If you still face an issue you have no way but to find the dependency of those modules from the vendors themselves.